# Iterate username and usergroup in JSP

Tags: jsp, business-objects

I am trying to write a JSP code that will bring all usernames and their groups from an application. The code will log into the application using admin userid and pwd and bring all usernames and groups in the application. But my code is returning only the Admin id and group.

How can I iterate it so that it bring back all the user ids and groups?

Below is the code. Appreciate your help.

```
ISessionMgr sm = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
      ies = sm.logon(UserName, password, cms, auth);
      IInfoStore iStore = (IInfoStore)ies.getService("","InfoStore");
      String Query = "SELECT top 10 * FROM CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS WHERE SI_KIND = 'User'AND SI_NAME = '" + UserName + "'";
      IInfoObjects iObjects = iStore.query(Query);
     
      for(int i=0;i<iObjects.size();i++)
       {
                  
          if (iObjects.size()> 0)
          {
                               
            iObject = (IInfoObject) iObjects.get(i);     
            user = (IUser)iObject;
            java.util.Set usergroups = (java.util.Set)user.getGroups();                
            Iterator iter = usergroups.iterator();
            out.println("<tr bgcolor = lightblue><td>" + user.getTitle() + "</tr></td>");
            String groupName = null;
                
            while (iter.hasNext())


                    {
  id = String.valueOf(iter.next());
                         String Query1 = "SELECT top 10 * FROM CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS WHERE SI_KIND = 'UserGroup' AND SI_ID = '" + id + "'";
                         IInfoObjects iObjects1 = iStore.query(Query1);


  for(int j=0;j<iObjects1.size();j++)
  {


                         iObject1 = (IInfoObject) iObjects1.get(j);
                         groupName = iObject1.getTitle();
                         out.println("<td>" + groupName + "<br></tr></td>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your applications business logic, but I'll give it a shot.
It looks like you are narrowimg your SQL query to only return the user which's username is the usename with which was logged in.

Line 2 you are logging in with object UserName (by the way, it would be useful if you would explain where variable `UserName` comes from) and on line 4 you are using the same object in the SQL where you query from all users.

So my guess is that if you remove the `AND SI_NAME = '" + UserName + "'"` part from your first SQL, it will work like you want it to.